# How to create a folder with name more than 260 charaters

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-server-2008, directory, windows-7-x64

I want to pragmatically create a folder hierarchy. But the problems is in some cases the folder name comes beyond 260 characters and the folder creation getting failed. I have created this folder hierarchy using Win32 File Namespaces.
I want to create a folder structure in the following format. **DRIVE_LETTER:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FOLDER3\FOLDER4........\FOLDER(N-1)\FOLDER(N)**

FOLDER1, FOLDER2, FOLDER3 etc are names of the folder. These names are of length more than 260 characters
for eg:

***FOLDER1*** name is  qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

***FOLDER2*** name is mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewqmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq

like this will go.

How can I over come this folder name/file name name length constraint.

The OS : Windows 7 64 bit and Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

Please help

Comment: You'll get error code 123: ERROR_INVALID_NAME. Here is the code you might test: `CreateDirectory(L"\\\\?\\C:\\qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm", NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

MSDN's [CreateDirectory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains you exactly this:

> To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode
>   version of the function and prepend `\\?\` to the path. For more
>   information, see Naming a File.

See also: [Should I deal with files longer than MAX_PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825798/should-i-deal-with-files-longer-than-max-path/2825881#2825881)

> NTFS support filenames up to 32K (32,767 wide characters). You need
>   only use correct API and correct syntax of filenames. The base rule
>   is: the filename should start with `\\?\` like `\\?\C:\Temp`. The same
>   syntax you can use with UNC: `\\?\Server\share\Path`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these two tricks:

- To create a folder structure with length of path more than 260 characters, like `C:\folder1\folder2\...\folder20`, you can create `C:\folder19`, `C:\folder20` and then move `folder20` with all its subfolders into `C:\folder19`, then create `C:\folder18` and move `C:\folder19` with `folder20` inside `C:\folder18`. Repeat until you finished creating this structure.
- You can use the `\\?\C:\folder1\folder2\...\folder20` notation to create your path. More information is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx (search for words *Maximum Path Length Limitation*).

Comment: Looks like these tricks no longer work on Windows 10. Both give an error saying the path is too long.

Answer (score 1):

A single *path component* (e.g. a folder name or file name) is limited by the value of `MaximumComponentLength` returned by [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993). This is in theory filesystem-specific but *in practice* is always 255.

So, you can't do what you asked unless you make your own filesystem driver which supports longer file components. What you *can* do, however is to create a path with **total length** longer than 260 characters, as has been pointer in other answers.