# What is the maximum number of services limited by the Android OS?

Tags: android, android-service

I am looking into building an app with a plugin architecture in which each plugin is a service.

But before going ahead and starting to implement this, I would like to know how many such plugins can co-exist in a given Android device.

Obviously, the amount of memory available is a key factor, but other than that:

1. Does the Android OS limit the number of services that can be **installed** on a device?
2. Does the Android OS limit the number of services that can **run concurrently** on a device?
3. If so, what are the limits?
4. Do the limits vary with the Android version?

Comment: it all depends on your device memory

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen Please note the following in my original post: *Obviously, the amount of memory available is a key factor, but **other than that:**"* IOW, I would like to get an authoritative answer whether there are built-in-by-design limits in the OS, similar to [MAX_PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2825798/2946787) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would like to get an authoritative answer whether there are built-in-by-design limits in the OS

I am afraid you will NOT get any authoritative answer, because any vendor (like Sony, Samsung, HTC) can not only add their crapware to the system but also tweak any other parameters of the platform. And there's are various Androids, like AOSP's one but also i.e. CyanogenMod's. They usually do not publish such info, so basically in would be just blind guess.