# Which encoding scheme does Windows use?

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding

I want to save information about existing SMB shares on my Windows system to a file and have determined max number of characters that can be used by the following properties to be:

```
Share Name: 80 chars
Scope Name: 256 chars
Path: 260 chars
Description: 256 chars
```

How do I calculate the space (in bytes) that will be occupied by this information?

Comment: Windows internally uses UTF-16 for just about everything. But I'm not sure if there are cases where a pair of surrogates would count as one character instead of two. In any case you may want to use a different encoding for writing to a file.

Comment: That 260 limit you hitting is known as `MAX_PATH`.  And a path can be longer if the application code uses the right naming conventions.  Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825798/should-i-deal-with-files-longer-than-max-path